# trigger in azure data factory that runs daily basis only between 8:30 and 6:00 with 30 minutes interval

Tags: triggers, azure-data-factory

I need to create a trigger on daily basis between 8:30 and 6:00 with 30 minutes interval in azure data factory. can any of u please help me with steps to create?

Answer (score 0):

Please follow my configuration as below:

[image]

It would be triggered every day at the specific time.

One little issue: It will be triggered at `18:30` because the limitation of configuration.You could just set a [if-condition activity](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/data-factory/control-flow-if-condition-activity) before all of your stuffs to judge if it is `18:30`,then just leave the pipeline.